# How to display CodeRush menu item in VS?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, coderush

I just installed CodeRush to my VS and when I run VS for the first time after installation it showed me a dialog asking if I'm experienced user. While the dialog was visible I could see that there was new menu item in VS named DevExpress. There was a small check box on that dialog saying something about menu items that I probably should have checked. As I did not the menu items disappeared just after I clicked OK.

I cannot make that menu item reappear. Can somebody help me with this ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**DevExpress Menu Disappearing**

Typically the menu disappearing is not an *evaluation issue*. Instead this is the normal behaviour of *CodeRush Xpress*.

This menu can indeed be brought back. This needs to be done for each Major version (2 - 3 of these each year). Here are the [instructions for doing so with 10.1](http://www.coderjournal.com/2010/04/show-coderush-xpress-10-1-menu-in-visual-studio/)

However it may be enough to know that the options are available through the use of the *CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+O* shortcut

**CodeRush Xpress**

The Xpress of CodeRush is not an evaluation version although it is a cut down version.
(Trial of full version of CodeRush [available here)](http://devexpress.com/Downloads/Visual_Studio_Add-in/)
It is Free to use with VS2005, VS2008 and VS2010 because Microsoft paid DevExpress to licence it to every user of (the Pro versions and higher of) these products.

Along with this, Microsoft also wrote several conditions into this agreement.

The first of these appears to have been the removal of the DevExpress menu from the main menu bar.

Additionally in version 10.1 and higher (required if you want to use CodeRush Xpress with VS2010) several other functions were also removed at the request of MS (but only whilst running under VS2010 - these functions remain whilst using 10.1 with earlier versions of Studio)

This is indeed a shame but as MS paid for this product they are entitled to have a say in what goes into it.

Comment: This s what I call great answer! I don't really understand why Microsoft wants this... But anyway I'd like to know what are the other limitation on CodeRush Xpress. It seems to me that not even basic rename works in CodeRush Xpress(it cannot be invoked by F2 and it only invoked VS default rename - see my question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881459/coderush-not-working). Or I can read the details myself if you can state some sources of your information.

Comment: Perhaps try my blog: I have not attempted to list all the limitations are but you can read my post on CodeRush vs CodeRush express here -> http://rorybecker.blogspot.com/2009/07/coderush-vs-coderush-xpress.html and also my more recent post on the changes in CodeRush Xpress 10.1 here -> http://rorybecker.blogspot.com/2010/05/coderush-101-hits-rtm.html I hope this helps. If you have any other questions, feel free to contact me on twitter (@rorybecker) or via mail if you prefer (rorybecker@gmail.com)

Comment: Of course if you'd prefer, I will be happy to answer questions on SO. I'm always happy to earn a bit of rep :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your blog is really interesting. I've installed evaluation version of CodeRush Pro and it solved most of issues. I'm missing only one Resharper feature so far but maybe I'll ask a new question about that. That will also give you a possibility to earn some rep.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> brings up CodeRush preferences.

Comment: Well I know that but what about the menu item? How do I make it reappear ?

Comment: I think the menu not being available is something to do with it being evaluation version. Mine is no longer around either.

Answer (score 0):

To enable the menu in Visual Studio 2008, windows 7 32 bit of the CodeRush Express 11.2.11, enter the HideMenu key in your registry and restart VS:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Developer Express\CodeRush for VS\11.2]
"HideMenu"=dword:00000000
```

Regards

Comment: Welcome to SO. The information you provide in your answer is already covered by a link provided in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had to open Visual Studio in Admin mode.
Just right click on the visual studio icon and select run as administrator.

Comment: This isn't so much an answer as it is a workaround.