# CodeRush not working?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, resharper, coderush

I was using Resharper and I wanted to try CodeRush so I suspended Resharper and installed CodeRush Xpress. When I installed CodeRush version 2010.1.4 (from [this](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/CodeRushX/) downlad page) the shortcuts did not work.

I tried F2 and other shortcuts that schold work but they did not. However I was able to invoke some CodeRush functions by clicking right mouse button and choosing "Refractor" from the drop down menu. When I choose it there is CodeRush action menu where I can select for example "Rename" but as I select it invokes VS default rename function, not the one of CodeRush.

In the menu of VS I see DevXpress menu item that has only one choise - upload or load CodeRush.

I tried to fix it by uninstaling Resharper and then reinstalling CodeRush but the result is the same. Any ideas on how to fix it or what I did wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodeRush Xpress is a cut down (Free) version of the full version of CodeRush. It is not the trial or evaluation version

If you're looking to compare with Resharper, then you should check out the [trial of full CodeRush](http://devexpress.com/Downloads/Visual_Studio_Add-in/) rather than CodeRush Xpress. You may also want to consider installing [this community plugin](http://code.google.com/p/dxcorecommunityplugins/wiki/CR_ReSharperCompatibility)

I have the full version installed at the moment and so cannot double check this, but under CodeRush full, some shortcuts (like <kbd>F2</kbd>) are not enabled by default.

If you stick with CodeRush Xpress, the main shortcut you should look to use under CodeRush Xpress is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> (the CodeRush/Refactor key)

Also useful is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> (Options)

Also consider [Restoring the DevExpress menu](http://www.coderjournal.com/2010/04/show-coderush-xpress-10-1-menu-in-visual-studio/)

Comment: In general CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+O  IDE\Shortcuts. The F2 shortcut (In CodeRush at least) is on this page at Refactor!\Alternate Bindings

Comment: Which other shortcuts do you feel are not enabled?

Comment: In my CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+O IDE\Shortcuts in page Refactor! there is no subcategory Alternate Bindings... So I cannot find it. And when I press CRTL+` and then chose rename, instead of renaming in code it pops out default VS renaming window... That's the main problem but it also does not show errors in code(red underline).

Comment: The features you are expecting are CodeRush features and you only have CodeRush Xpress installed. CodeIssues (the squigglies) is a pro feature and so is the inline renaming. MS required that CodeRush Xpress would redirect to the MS versions of refactorings where they were available. What you are looking for is available in the full version of CodeRush or in it's trial